# External redirects in exception logic is not working on Tomcat 8.5.39

Tags: spring, tomcat

I'm setting up exception handling logic for a multipart project with common error page (that is hosted in other part of the project). When I tried to redirect to external URL on exception, tomcat 8.5.39 is showing default error instead. Funny thing is, this seems to work just fine in tomcat 8.5.38

I've tried many different exception handling techniques, but they all seem not to work for external redirects.

So currently, i have something like this in my web.xml file:

```xml
...
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/error404</location>
    </error-page>
...
```

and for my Spring controller,

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/error")
public class ErrorHandler{
...
    @GetMapping(value = "error404")
    public String error404(){
        return "redirect:http://{myproject}/{404errorPage}";
    }
...
}
```

I'm expecting this code to redirect the user to http://{myproject}/{404errorPage} when 404 error occurs, which works just fine in tomcat 8.5.38. But on 8.5.39, they seem to have changed error handling logic, and it will display default error page(browser default 404 page).

Any input or idea would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: I've done some more digging, and found out that the communication header is showing 404 for 8.5.39 , and 302 for 8.5.38 which is what i want. Everything else (including the redirect location) looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [regression](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63312) in 8.5.39 which is fixed in the just released 8.5.40.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the fix :) ill go ahead and upgrade to 8.5.40